# Exception while using getStream.io React component

Tags: reactjs, getstream-io

I am using the getStream.io React component as follows:

```
<StreamApp
    apiKey='apiKey'
    appId='appId'
    token='token'
>
  <FlatFeed />
</StreamApp>
```

When I am hard-coding the above values, I do not see any issue and the app works correctly.

However, when I try to pass the token as state variable ( Token is generated on the server side and returned to user on client side on signup/login), I get an exception as follows :

[image]

Has anyone else seen this issue before? If yes, how did you get around this issue. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: if the token prop is not a valid JWT token (eg. an empty or "regular" string) you will get this error. did you try logging the state variable just to verify that the valid token is passed?

Comment: Thanks @TommasoBarbugli. Yes, that is what was happening, initial state of the token was empty and hence it was throwing this error on startup